# How to replace first occurrence string in html file with shell script

Tags: html, bash, shell

In html file, I need to replace only the first occurrence of:

```
<table id="any string" >
```

"any string" is whatever inside the " ". There is an space before the last > character.

expected output:

```
<table id="new string">
```

I know that maybe a `sed -i` can make it but i don't know how to match the "any string" part and only the first occurrence.

Comment: Please [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858). I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed` grouping and back referencing, you can exclude the text within the quotes as well as the space at the end.

```
$ sed -i.backup '0,/table id/s/\(table id="\).*\("\) /\1new string\2/' input_file
<table id="new string">
```

This will create a backup of the original file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you `any string` actually means *any* string, as in you don't know what it is and it could be anything, you have to use the quotes as delimiters.  You mentioned `sed` so here's a simple `sed` solution:

```
# GNU sed needs -r for extended regexp, macOS sed needs -E for this
# s means for substitute
# / slashes are delimiters surrounding the paaterns, /before/after/
# [^ ] means any character that is *not* a space
# + means one or more of those characters
# followed by a space
# (.+) means one or more of any character, and remember what it is
# \1 use that first remembered pattern

sed -r 's/table id="[^ ]+ (.+)"/table id="new \1"/' file.html
```

So it will match a table with an ID in double quotes, which includes a space, and replace everything in the ID up to that space with "new".

Examples:

```
<table id="any string" > -> <table id="new string" >
<table id="compact striped" > -> <table id="new striped" >
<table id="data compact striped" > -> <table id="new compact striped" >
```

If `any string` actually means any string at all, not necessarily with a space (eg "foo"), and `new string` means any new string (eg bar), is the problem is a whole lot simpler:

```
sed -r 's/table id=".+"/table id="new"/' file.html
```

Examples:

```
<table id="foo bar" > -> <table id="new" >
<table id="jabberwocky" > -> <table id="new" >
```

Comment: GNU sed has `-E`.